# How to "correct" the roundness of the earth leading to ellipsis instead of circle in react leaflet

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, react-leaflet

I'm trying to programatically "draw" a circle with multiple Marker with React leaflet.

I'm doing it with cosinus and sinus trying to calculate theirs coordinate from the center point ...

But the more I'm near the pole the more the circle is an ellipssis ... Is it a way to transform the calculus to take this into account ?

In this example I'm in Oulu (near the pole) If you just change the x var into '0' you'll notice that the markers are now in circle !

please see this [CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-elipsis-instead-of-circle-ptf43?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

Because a Leaflet map is a projection of a sphere onto a flat map, distortions will happen near the poles. You want to **project** your spherical Lat/Lng into flat Points, calculate the marker placements in flat Points and then **unproject** the points back to spherical LatLng.

Comment: Well ok ... But how to **project** such things ? Is there a formula for this ? 
And as there is distortion due to the flattening ... I won't be able to have a drawn perfect circle if I want it to be of x meters radius (all the way around) ? ... Then in [the leaflet docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) the radius isn't really in meters isn't it ?

Comment: Leaflet map object has `project` and `unproject` methods that convert from lat/lng to points: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-project. You can also calculate meters per pixel at a specific zoom level and draw your circle x pixels wide.